# QGIS application : Must construct a QApplication before a QWidget

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, gis, qgis

I installed latest version (3.28) of qgis using network installer. As per the documentation, we need to instantiate `QgsApplication` instead of `QApplication` before doing anything. `QgsApplication` is subclass of `QApplication`. Here is my `main` function :

```cpp
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

        QgsApplication a(argc, argv, true);

        QgsApplication::setPrefixPath("C:/OSGeo4W/apps/qgis", true);
        QgsApplication::initQgis();

        QWidget w;
        w.showMaximized();

        return a.exec();
}
```

It compiles without any issue, but when I run it, I get an error `QWidget: Must construct a QApplication before a QWidget`and application exits.

I tried switching multiple `Qgis` versions. I checked `Qgis` official documentation and code example, everywhere they're starting the application in similar way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing I noticed in my project is that it compiles without any issues in release mode, but gives a `QWidget: Must construct a QApplication before a QWidget` error in debug mode.

The reason for this is that the installed `Qgis` version on the system is a release version. When I compile it in debug mode, it conflicts with `Qgis's` release version, hence the error.

So, in order to compile the project in debug version, I'll need to install a debug version of `Qgis library` first.

Comment: This was helpful for me when developing a QGIS C++ plugin. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Well, look at This Example which I create and use `QgsApplication`.
You didn't need `QWidget` you need `QgsMapCanvas`!

[QgsMapCanvas](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsMapCanvas.html) inherited from `QGraphicsView` and is The Base of QGIS Map.

```
#include <qgsapplication.h>
#include <qgsmapcanvas.h>
#include <qgsmaplayer.h>
#include <qgsrasterlayer.h>

int  main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    // Start the QGIS application
    QgsApplication  app(argc, argv, true);

    QgsApplication::setPluginPath("/usr/lib64");
    QgsApplication::setPrefixPath("/usr", true);
    QgsApplication::setPkgDataPath("/usr/share/qgis");
    app.initQgis();

    // Create a map canvas
    QgsMapCanvas *canvas = new QgsMapCanvas();

    canvas->setWindowTitle("QGIS");
    canvas->resize(800, 600);

    // Show the canvas
    canvas->show();

    // Start the application loop
    return app.exec();
}
```

[image]

and If you want to put MapCanvas inside a Widget you can do this:

```
#include <QGridLayout>
#include <qgsapplication.h>
#include <qgsmapcanvas.h>
#include <qgsmaplayer.h>
#include <qgsrasterlayer.h>

int  main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    // Start the QGIS application
    QgsApplication  app(argc, argv, true);

    QgsApplication::setPluginPath("/usr/lib64");
    QgsApplication::setPrefixPath("/usr", true);
    QgsApplication::setPkgDataPath("/usr/share/qgis");
    app.initQgis();

    // Create a map canvas
    QgsMapCanvas *canvas = new QgsMapCanvas();

    canvas->setWindowTitle("Load TMS map like OSM in QGIS");

    QWidget      w;
    QGridLayout *layout = new QGridLayout(&w);

    w.resize(800, 600);
    layout->setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);

    w.layout()->addWidget(canvas);

    w.showMaximized();

    return app.exec();
}
```

and This is my `.pro` file:

```
QT       += core gui xml
greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

CONFIG += c++17

# You can make your code fail to compile if it uses deprecated APIs.
# In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
#DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0
INCLUDEPATH +=  /usr/include/qgis
LIBS += -lqgis_core -lqgis_gui -lqgis_analysis -lqgis_app

SOURCES += \
    main.cpp 



# Default rules for deployment.
qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target
```